# Rails: how to find record before last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can find last record in my table like in example below, but what if I want to find record before last, e.g. (last-1) or (last-2)..? 
I have this example in my each loop:

```
Table.find(:last, :conditions => {:dogovor_id => p.id}).id
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").first           # last
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").offset(1).first # last - 1
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").offset(2).first # last - 2
```

Answer (score 36):

Another easier to remember way is: `Model.last(2).first`

Answer (score 31):

**Rails 4:**

```
Model.last(2).first
```

In **Rails 5+** you can use new self-explanatory [accessor methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23583):

```
Model.second_to_last
Model.third_to_last
```

You can also use negative indices.

Second to last:

```
Model.all[-2]
```

The 10th to last:

```
Model.all[-10]
```

**NB**: As pointed by @AndrewSchwartz, this method can be more problematic (consuming) on large tables. This method first loads all the records and then processes them, whereas `second_to_last` generates more optimized query with LIMIT and OFFSET

Comment: According to my SQL logs, `Model.all[-2]` does not limit what is loaded from the db, while `second_to_last` correctly puts an `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` in the SQL. If you have a lot of records, that could get *very* problematic.

Comment: And there are others, I bet, [not well-known methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63567111/52499).

Answer (score 2):

Even if accepted answer works:

```
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").first           # last
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").offset(1).first # last - 1
Table.where(:dogovor_id => p.id).order("id DESC").offset(2).first # last - 2
```

'first' method is an array method, so concerning performance its better to use 'limit' method which is an ActiveRecord method and attaches LIMIT clause to SQL query:

```
Table.where(dogovor_id: p.id).order(id: :desc).offset(1).limit(1) # last - 1
```

Comment: `first` is also an ActiveRecord method, which attaches `LIMIT`. Using `first` returns single record, while using `limit` returns single record wrapped in an array, which is actually less performant.

Answer (score 0):

we can use:

```
Model.last(2).first
```

OR
we write simple,it work only for last third record .

```
Model.second_to_last
```