# How do I pick the last and the second to last entries in a blog model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model, blog_posts which has a field "published_at". I'd like to select the latest two blogs from that model to display on my homepage. Not sure how to structure that though.

At the moment I have a work around that takes a slice of the data but it keeps failing when I have nothing in the table, rather than fix this I feel there is probably a better way to retrieve the data.

I need to select the blogs in separate calls, for example

`@blog_post.latestpost`, `@blog_post.secondlatestpost`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? :

```
class BlogPost < Activerecord::Base
  def self.latestpost
    order("published_at DESC").limit(1).first
  end

  def self.secondlatestpost
    order("published_at DESC").offset(1).limit(1).first
  end
end
```

Use it like this :

```
BlogPost.secondlatestpost
```

or

```
BlogPost.latestpost
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would work great! I'll give it a go, thanks. I didn't even think about putting it like this.

Comment: Assuming I can run a != nil against this on an if statement so some code doesn't load if its not there?

Comment: Yes. One thing to note, is when you have only one record in the database. The last will return the record, the second last will return nil.

Comment: How to I account for that in my if? I tried if @blog_post.secondlatestpost != nil but it still seems to fails heroku - weirdly it works on my dev machine. Is this a db related issue? should i ask it another way?

Comment: I'd rather do `if BlogPost.secondlatestpost` (you don't really need to check for `nil`, the only false values in ruby are `nil` and `false` and the result should obviously not be `false` :-)). What's your error message?

Comment: cool - works! I not have another error relating to another time im using a slice method, so im going to try and pull it using the method you describe above :-)

Comment: `.limit(1)` isn't necessary, as `.first` or `.last` already limit the the SQL query

Comment: @BenoitGarret what if there are only 2 records in the list, it will always give last

Answer (score 9):

You could also do:

```
BlogPost.order(:published_at).last # for the last post
BlogPost.order(:published_at).offset(1).last # for the second to last post
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Rails 5 you can use `BlogPost.second_to_last`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-second_to_last

Answer (score 8):

At least since Rails 4.x you can specify how many last records you want. E.g. to fetch last 2 records:

```
BlogPost.last(2)    # BlogPost.last(2).first will return the second last post
```

The same goes for `first()`. There are also methods `second()`, `third()`, `fourth()`, `fifth()`, [`forty_two()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L174-L198). And starting with Rails 5.x, `second_to_last()`, [`third_to_last()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.4.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L143-L262).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ActiveRecord

```
BlogPost.order("published_at DESC").second
```

Although I think going with `offset` and `limit` is the somewhat cleaner and more portable version. Internally `second` (and `third`, `fourth`) use the `find_nths` method. Documented here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/second