# Rails, find object before last e.g -1

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Afternoon all,

I have this query and was wondering how i could convert this into finding the last but one record so instead of .last it would get -1. ( I have read [Rails: how to find record before last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015020/rails-how-to-find-record-before-last) but i'm not sure how to convert this query)

The code;

```
Model.last.hotels.find_by_winner(true)
```

many thanks in advance! Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Model.order('id desc').offset(1).first.hotels.find_by_winner(true)
```