# How would I create a `second_to_last` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'd like to create a method `second_to_last` that is similar to `last` but returns the second to last record from a model instead of the last record. I thought this would be trivial since the SQL for last is:

```
Select * from "users".* FROM "Users" ORDERED BY "ORDERED BY" "users"."id" DECS LIMIT 1
```

I have to find a way to change the `Limit 1` to `Limit 2` and then select the first element. Am I thinking correctly? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: how to find record before last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015020/rails-how-to-find-record-before-last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track.  Try something like this:

```
User.order("created_at DESC").limit(2).last
```

This should return the second-to-last record.

There are even ways to extend Rails with your new method but that is probably beyond the scope of your question.

Even better, you can use User.last(2).  I dosen't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 4):

If this is really a rails questions, you don't need to do it in SQL anyway. Just do:

```
User.order("id DESC").offset(1).first
```

Quite literally, it executes this sql query:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the SQL that will generate.

Comment: That looks like it'd get the second row in the table based on the `:id` order, not the second-to-last row as asked for by the OP. I see no 'desc' modifier for the `ORDER BY` to reverse the order.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, you're right! I've included "DESC" in the order clause and added the new SQL.